# How to define a recursively defined set properly?

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory, logic, definition, recursion

We can define sets recursively. For example we can say

$x\in S\iff x=1 \vee \exists y\in S: y+2=x$

But how can we write $S$ ?

I.e. how can we describe $S$ in a way we are normaly used to describe a set. I.e. extensionaly or intensionaly?

In the form $S=\{x\in\mathbb{N}|\phi(x)\}$ (intensionaly)? Because I think that that **recursively defining a set S implies a intensional definition of a subset of the superset of $S$** (The subset is $S$) in this case it is $\mathbb{N}$.

(Reasonably the set can also be written extensionally $S=\{1,3,5,....\}$ but this is not the point of my question I am interested in the implicit  intensional definition given by the recursion)

I have made a previous example with **propositional formulas** in a language,

A language consists of an ALPHABET and a GRAMMAR.

An alphabet $\mathcal{A}$ is a union of three different sets, we will call the element of an alphabet symbols. The first set are the symbols for the propositional variables like $A,B,C....$, the second set is the set of logical symbols $T,F,\wedge,\vee,\implies,\iff$ and the third set are non-logical symbols like $(,)$

The set of all propositional formulas  is similair to the set $S$ above because there are some initial elements and some elements we can derive from the initial elements recursively.

> Let $\mathcal{F}$ be the set of all propositional formulas. **We want
>   to define this set in such a way** if we take a element from
>   it:$\phi\in\mathcal{F}$ then we want to say that this is equivalent
>   to **the desired statement**: $\phi\in \{1\}\times V\vee \exists!
>  \psi_1,\psi_2\in\mathcal{F},a\in\{\vee,\implies,\wedge,\iff\}: \phi=(a,\psi_1,\psi_2)$. $V$ is the set of all propositional variables
>   we have defined extensionaly in beforehand: $V=\{A,B,C,D,E,...\}$.

For the sake of simplicity I have just looked at the set of binary operators but one can also do the same for other operators and also can use another symbols like $\{1,2,3,4\}$. The important thing is that we can distinguish in this case the triples from one another. I have simplified even further and assumed in the following that $\implies$ is the only logical operator we have to consider and which happens to be a binary logical operator.

$$\mathcal{F}=\bigcup_{n\in\mathbb{N_0}}T_n$$

$$T_0= \{1\}\times V\quad\text{and}\quad T_n=\bigcup_{(j,k)\in\{1,...,n-1\}^{2}}\{2\}\times T_{n-1}\times T_j\cup \{2\}\times T_k\times T_{n-1}$$

> My question is first of all whether my definition of $\mathcal{F}$
>   makes sense, i.e. whether I actually have defined all propositional
>   formulas?
>
> Whether there is alternative that is so general that it does not make
>   use of the natural numbers because this definition was motivated by
>   someone elses answer to an old question of mine and I am not sure if
>   his understanding of $\mathcal{F}$ matches my definition and
>   unfortunately this person does not react to my comment anymore (link
>   to the question:
>   [Induction over propositional formulas](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3312734/induction-over-propositional-formulas/3312818?noredirect=1#comment6822010_3312818)).
>   And he seems to make no use of natural numbers. He explicitly said
>   **structural induction** and not induction over the natural numbers.
>
> Whether taking an element from this defined set is equivalent to the
>   **desired statement** and how I can prove it, especialy the uniqueness.
>
> Finally I want to ask whether I can somehow derive a **general
>   definition** of all inductively defined sets from this example.
>   Because every *inductively defined set* in its nature has initial
>   elements which could be described with a generl $T_0$ and some
>   advanced elements which are in some $T_n$ and deduced from the initial
>   elements.

Comment: You could just define $S_0=\{1\}$ and $S_{n+1}=S_n\cup\{y+2~|~y\in S_n\}$ and $S=\bigcup_nS_n$.

Comment: Section 10.2 of [my book](https://infinitedescent.xyz/dl/infdesc.pdf) is relevant. Particularly Definition 10.2.15, which constructs an inductively defined set from a set of inductive rules. [Edit: the comment above this one is exactly what Def 10.2.15 gives you in this case—here the basic element is $1$ and the (unique, unary) constructor is $n \mapsto n + 2$.]

Comment: There is more to "inductive" or recursive definitions of *sets* than just the ordinary "base step + inductive step" that one has in elementary *number theory*.  Notice that you have indexed the object $T_k$ with natural numbers (I think).  In set theory one might have a similar set up but using indexing by ordinal numbers or cardinal numbers, which can give individual indexes that are infinite.  This is known as *transfinite induction*.

Answer (score 3):

*This isn't fully an answer to the question, since it doesn't address the OP's idea of using propositional logic, but I think it may still be useful to them and it's certainly too long for a comment*.

---

What you're looking for is the general notion of **definition by (possibly transfinite) recursion**, and in particular of **least fixed points** of (monotone) operators on sets.

- Pet peeve: *induction* is a proof technique, *recursion* is a construction method. We prove by induction but build by recursion.

---

A "definition" like  $$x\in S\iff x=1 \vee \exists y\in S: y+2=x$$ can be thought of as describing an operator $\mathcal{O}$ on sets of natural numbers given by $$\mathcal{O}(X)=X\cup\{1\}\cup\{a: \exists y\in X(y+2=x)\}.$$

Now the important thing to note is that $\mathcal{O}$ has **fixed points** - for example, $\mathcal{O}(\mathbb{N})=\mathbb{N}$. The idea of iterating $\mathcal{O}$ until some "completed" set appears corresponds to looking for the *least* fixed point of $\mathcal{O}$:

> If $I$ is some "base set" and $\mathcal{O}:\mathcal{P}(I)\rightarrow\mathcal{P}(I)$ is some operator on subsets of $I$, the *least fixed point of $\mathcal{O}$* is the unique (if it exists) set $S\subseteq I$ satisfying $(1)$ $\mathcal{O}(S)=S$ and $(2)$ for every $S'\subseteq I$ with $\mathcal{O}(S')=S'$ we have $S\subseteq S'$.

**Not every operation on sets has fixed points at all**: for example, consider the *complement* operation $\mathcal{C}: X\mapsto I\setminus X$ on any nonempty "base set" $I$. However, there are conditions which guarantee the existence of fixed points, and indeed least fixed points, the most common of which is *monotonicity*: $\mathcal{O}$ is monotonic iff $\mathcal{O}(X)\supseteq X$ for all $X\subseteq I$. Given a monotonic operator $\mathcal{O}$ we can "iterate it through the ordinals" as follows: $$A_0=\emptyset, \quad A_{\alpha+1}+\mathcal{O}(A_\alpha), \quad A_\lambda=\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}A_\alpha\mbox{ for $\lambda$ limit}.$$ Eventually this process stabilizes: there is some ordinal $\eta$ such that $A_\eta=A_\theta$ for all $\theta\ge\eta$. Using monotonicity we can prove that $A_\eta$ is indeed the least fixed point of $\mathcal{O}$.

Additional properties of $\mathcal{O}$ can make this process simpler. Some operations, for example, are *finitely based* - they satisfy $\mathcal{O}(X)=\bigcup_{F\subseteq X\mbox{ finite}}\mathcal{O}(F)$. Such an $\mathcal{O}$ (if also monotonic) stabilizes at level $\omega$, that is, we just need to iterate through the natural numbers. Bt in general larger ordinals may be needed, and it's a good exercise to construct an example of this.

Comment: What is this set $\{a: \exists y\in X(y+2=x)\}$ ?

Comment: @New2Math What do you mean, what is that set? It's exactly what it looks like. It's a set depending on $X$ which may or may not be the same as $X$. For instance, if $X=\{5\}$ then $\{a: \exists y\in X(y+2=a)\}=\{3\}$. Now, I suspect that what you really want is to ascribe a meaning to the "set equation" $$X=\{a: \exists y\in X(y+2=a)\}.$$ If so, this fits the method in my answer: solutions to that equation are exactly fixed points of the map $X\mapsto \{a:\exists y\in X(y+2=a)\}$. You probably want the "canonical" solution, which is the least fixed point of that map.